Teamviewer type package for raspberry pi
I have tried using a spare windows laptop with Anydesk on it.  But the laptop keeps going to sleep.  I was wondering if there was something I could run on a RPi.
This question has an answer as Anydesk.  But its is 7 years old.  I was wondering if there are more superior alternatives now?

For Raspberry Pi, a boxed solution has recently appeared for connecting via a browser from anywhere on the planet.

It’s often extremely useful to be able to access your Raspberry Pi’s
desktop remotely. There are a number of technologies which can be used
to do this, including VNC, and of course the X protocol itself. But
they can be hard to configure, particularly when you are attempting to
access a machine on a different local network; and of course with the
transition to Wayland in Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm, classic X remote
desktop support is no longer available.
We wanted to be able to provide you with this functionality with our
usual “it just works” approach. Enter Raspberry Pi Connect.

More details are available at this link.
